# OCTAVE - plot values from 2 functions

Tags: plot, charts, octave

**Greetings,
i have an Issue with an Octave Script i'm making concerning Numeric Integration.
I have 3 functions: 1st calculates Heuler integration; 2nd calculates Heun Integration; 3rd should plot the line chart of heuler and heun together in same window.**

The problem is that 1st and 2nd functions are working very well, but the 3rd function called previsao() no matter what i do always throw the error:
A(I,J): column index out of bounds; value 1 out of bound 0
previsao at line 124, column 7

**Line 124 is this one:** plt1 = plot(eul(:,x),eul(:,ti),heu(:,x),heu(:,ti));

**Here is the code for heuler**

```
function e = euler(x,ti,tf,h,fDerivada)

 xInicial = x;
 tInicial = ti;
 contador = 0;

 % inicia array na posição 1 a 0
  x(1) = 0;
 t(1) = 0;

 while(tInicial <= tf)

% implementa o método de Euler
xFinal = xInicial;
funcao = fDerivada(tInicial, xInicial);
xInicial = xInicial + h * funcao;

% insere valores nos arrays x e t e vai incrementando de posição no array
% vai dar origem à matriz com t e x 
x(contador + 1) = xInicial;
t(contador + 1) = tInicial;

tInicial = tInicial + h;

contador++;

 endwhile

 printf("\n");
 disp("Metodo de Euler:");
 % escreve a matriz em colunas
 [t', x']

 %gráfico 
 plt = plot(x);
 set(plt(1),"linewidth",2);
 set(plt(1),"color","r");
 xlabel("Tempo");
ylabel("Var dependente x");
title("Heuler");
legend("x");

 endfunction
```

**Heun Function**

```
function h = heun(x, ti, tf, h, fDerivada)

 xInicial = x;
 tInicial = ti;
 media = h/2;
 contador = 0;

 % inicia array na posição 1 a 0
 x(1) = 0;
 t(1) = 0;

while(tInicial <= tf)

% implementa o método de heun
xFinal = xInicial;
funcao = fDerivada(tInicial, xInicial);
% previsor
previsor = xInicial + h * funcao;
% cálculo com corretor
% var media = h/2
corretor = xInicial + media * (funcao + fDerivada(tInicial + h, previsor));

% insere valores nos arrays x e t e vai incrementando de posição no array
% vai dar origem à matriz com t e x 
x(contador + 1) = corretor;
t(contador + 1) = tInicial;

tInicial = tInicial + h;

contador++;

endwhile

printf("\n");
disp("Metodo de Heun:");
% escreve a matriz em colunas
[t', x']

% gráfico 
plt = plot(x);
set(plt(1),"linewidth",2);
set(plt(1),"color","r");
grid;
xlabel("Tempo");
ylabel("Var dependente x");
title("Heun");
legend("x");

endfunction
```

**The problematic function**

**It should plot both euler and heun chart in same window**

**previsao function**

```
function previsao(x, ti, tf, h, fDerivada)

% chama ambas as funções
% remover o ponto e virgula para fazer saida da matriz t, x
eul = euler(x,ti,tf,h,fDerivada);
heu = heun(x,ti, tf, h, fDerivada);

% gráfico comparativo entre ambas
plt1 = plot(eul(:,x),eul(:,ti),heu(:,x),heu(:,ti));
set(plt1(1),"linewidth",2);
set(plt1(1),"color","g");
set(plt1(2),"linewidth",2);
set(plt1(2),"color","r");
grid;
xlabel("var independente t");
ylabel("Var dependente x");
title("Metodos de integracao");
legend("Heuler","Heun");

endfunction
```

**Many thanks for a possible solution...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to debug such a problem is to enable debug_on_error

```
debug_on_error(1);
```

The run your script again. This time it will stop in previsao with a debug> prompt. Now you can instect "eul" and "heu", for example the first step would be

```
size(eul)
size(heu)
x
ti
```

then it should be obvious what the problem is. And for the future: Please try to strip down your problem to the essential parts where you have problems not "Here is my workspace with x files". And it always helps if the code can be copy&pasted to the interpreter and someone who wasn't to help can see the problem. In your case I would have to figure out which values I need for x, ti, tf, h, fDerivada to run your function.

EDIT: your function

```
function e = euler(x,ti,tf,h,fDerivada)
```

Doesn't write the return value so apparently eul is [] in this case and I'm sure Octave issues a warning, right? Btw, you shouldn't overwrite builtins like e, pi, i....

Comment: Many thanks for the tip. I used the debug command as you told and the size of eul = 0 0 ; size of heu = 1 1. I'm around the code and i don't know why the size of eul i = 0 0. I think the problem is there because the the size of heu = 1 1 (it has values i presume). So why does eul not haves values?